# Drawing a simple game board in Android

Tags: java, android

I have some C# experience, but im completly new to java. So i have some questions for someone with more experience.

I would like to draw a simple game board of for example 10x10 grey boxes. So i figured a 2d array might be useful:

```
int gameBoard[][] = new int[10][10];
```

For each board i would like to draw a grey rectangle, and place it it some control to be rendered on the device.

I suppose this can be done with an instance of `Paint` and `Canvas`

And this is where im stuck at the moment. What controls are best suited for this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/graphics-basics.html), it explains very clearly the differences between canvas, paint and bitmap and finishes with an example of an app that draws a colored rectangle and displays it in an ImageView. Hope it can be useful.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Better use GridView or TableView for the box structure. Further , if you will wand something to crawl over boxes, it will be another activity on the deskboard one. *There* you'll maybe use bitmaps. THis way you will save heaps of time.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably go with the TableLayout, which I guess is what Gangnus meant with TableView

There is a tutorial for TableLayout here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

In your case you would put 10 views in each of 10 rows. You can chose to create them in the xml file or from the java file.